# Can't count the null values of a dataframe in R

Tags: r, dataframe, null, na

I have imported a dataset from a CSV file to a data frame that has lots of null values, but I can't count the number of null values

[image]

```
install.packages("tidyverse")
library(tidyverse)
sample <- read.csv("sample.csv")
colSums(is.na(sample))
```

[image]

Comment: Missing values `NA` are printed as `NA`. What you have are empty strings `""`. `colSums(sample == "")` (And `NA` is different from `NULL` --- `NA` has length 1, `NULL` has length 0 and is not a valid entry for a cell in a data frame)

Comment: If you have "real" `NA` values and want to count empty-like, then mod GregorThomas' to `colSums(sample %in% c("",NA))`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like `end_station_name` is an empty string (not `NA`). Something like `sum(data$end_station_name == "")` would tell you how many rows have 'missing' (in your case 'empty') values for `end_station_name`.

Comment: Thanks for your response,sum(data$end_station_name == "") is worked